# Is it better to add a mostly n/a valued column to a fact table or should a new fact table be created to store the values for this column?

Tags: mysql, database-design, data

I am creating a data model for Dropbox data warehouse

Business process: a user interacting with the application

Grain:every page event by a user on the application.
Dimensions: files,date,user,page,event,step,session, referral etc…

Fact table: fileid,dateid,userid,pageid,eventid etc…

Question: Suppose the action was to share the video, then determine who the video was shared with and with what rights?

To answer the above question, should a “shareduserid” column be added to the current fact table where the column will be mostly empty or should a new fact table with only shared events be created?

Answer (score 0):

`dateid` -- Do not normalize any column that you will search via a "range" test on the Fact table.  Performance will be terrible.  Anyway, a date takes about the same amount of space as an id!

`shareduserid` -- Is this a 'boolean'?  Or an `id` pointing to a "user" table?  Is there only a single user that it can be shared with?

If single, but optional, user, NULLable makes sense.

If multiple, but optional, users, you must do it some other way.  Probably a many-to-many table with 2 columns and 2 indexes.

Sketch out the `SELECTs` before asking further questions.  (Sometimes this helps you answer your own questions.)